# How to setup binding between locale class and UI component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, binding

I am trying to figure out how to properly setup binding between my Locale class and an mxml file.

My main mxml file contains:

```
<mx:Button id="TMP" label="{Locale.getLocaleString('title'}"/>
```

I would like to display an empty string in the button's label until the locale file loads.  Once the locale file loads I would like to display what is returned by `getLocaleString('title')`.

I think that this is what Binding is intended for however I think that I am approaching it wrong.

[I know that I am not allowed to bind on a function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_8.html#194574).  So do I need to allow access (using a get function) to my `_dictionary` property?  What is the standard way to setup Binding for something like this?

This is my current `Locale` class.

```
public class Locale {

    private static var _dictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    public static function loadResources():void {...}

    public static function getLocaleString(featureID:String):String {
        if(_dictionary[featureID]==null){
            return "";
        }
        return _dictionary[featureID];
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you <a href="http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_8.html#194574">are allowed to bind to a function</a>. I don't know whether the resource manager dispatches the appropriate binding events, but I would suspect it does.

Comment: Note that any time you're creating static classes, you're likely going about it the wrong way...

Comment: @Amy You are allowed to bind to a function but how do you get it to update?

Comment: Why don't you use the `ResourceManager` provided by Flex? You could even [create resource bundles at runtime](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=l10n_6.html) if that's why you want to use your own class. An even better solution would be to use [BabelFx](http://www.babelfx.org/).

Comment: Dispatch the binding event.  For more on how binding works, check out http://www.slideshare.net/michael.labriola/diving-in-the-flex-data-binding-waters-presentation?src=embed . Unfortunately the recorded presentation is not working from adobe.tv right now, or I'd send you to that...it's so much better.  But this is better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

- Extend the `EventDispatcher`, make the class Bindable and dispatch an event when loading has completed. ([doc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_8.html#194574))
- Turn the class from a static class to a singleton ([doc1](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Singleton_Pattern-262.html), [doc2](http://query7.com/singleton-pattern-in-flex))

Here is my final code:

```
[Bindable(event="loaded")]
public class LocaleSingleton extends EventDispatcher{

    private var _dictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    public function LocaleSingleton(){/* Do check to make sure it is a singleton*/}

    public function get instance(){...}

    public function loadResources():void {
    ...
    dispatchEvent(new Event("loaded")); // Method in EventDispatcher
    }

    public function getLocaleString(featureID:String):String {
    if(_dictionary[featureID]==null){
        return "";
    }
    return _dictionary[featureID];
    }
}
```